# Tikzpicture introduces extra spacing?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, block

If I remove the `tikzpicture` in the following MWE, the `block` moves upward.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]{Title}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
            \draw (5pt,5pt) circle (10pt);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \begin{block}{Theorem}
            text
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How is this possible?

Does the `tikzpicture` introduce some space?

If I use a `resizebox` around the `tikzpicture` I get a division by zero, so it does have size zero, but still it moves the `block`. How is this possible?

In this specific case I can just move the `tikzpicture` below the `block`, but how can I remove the extra space added in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the `tikzpicture` directly, it is leaving vertical mode that shifts the `block`.  That includes a `tikzpicture`, or even an `\mbox{}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]{Title}
%        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
%            \draw (5pt,5pt) circle (10pt);
%        \end{tikzpicture}%
        \leavevmode%
        \begin{block}{Theorem}
            text
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, here it is without leaving vertical mode:

[image]

One solution to keep the `block` in vertical mode is to place it in a `\vbox`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]{Title}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
            \draw (5pt,5pt) circle (10pt);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        \vbox{\begin{block}{Theorem}
            text
        \end{block}}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps better is to put the `tikzpicture` as the first thing inside of the `block`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]{Title}
        \begin{block}{Theorem}
          \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
              \draw (5pt,5pt) circle (10pt);
          \end{tikzpicture}%
            text
        \end{block}%
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to prevent `tikzpicture` from leaving vertical mode?

Comment: @Carucel Please see edit.

Comment: I hope this is not too much of a perky question, but do you happen to know a solution that only involves the `tikzpicture`? The `tikzpicture` is actually included in a command of me like `\insertglobalcircle` and I would like to be able to use this command without changing the rest of the `frame`.

Comment: @Carucel You could put the original `tikzpicture` as the first thing  inside of the `block`.  Does that violate your requirement?

Comment: I would really like to be able to place the `tikzpicture` anywhere. I ended up doing `\ifvmode\vspace*{-1.2em}\else\fi` before the `tikzpicture`, which was not able without your help. Thank you!